# YouTube Content ID API insert asset returns 403

Tags: youtube-api

I am able to get and list assets using googleapiclient and oauth2client,
but when I try to add one, I get 403:

```
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 403 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/partner/v1/assets?alt=json returned "Forbidden". Details: "[{'message': 'Forbidden', 'domain': 'global', 'reason': 'forbidden'}]">
```

Edit:
here's the piece of code that does the insertion:

```
    def insert_asset(self, work_id=None, artist=None, title=None, isrc=None):
    body = {
        "kind": "youtubePartner#asset",
        "type": "sound_recording",
        "status": "active",
        "metadataMine": {
            "customId": work_id,
            "title": title,
            "isrc": isrc,
            "artist": [artist],
        },
    }
    return self.service_youtube_content_id.assets().insert(body=body).execute()
```

and the `service_youtube_content_id` is instantiated as

```
        self.service_youtube_content_id = build(
        "youtubePartner", "v1", http=self.http, static_discovery=False
    )
```

Comment: I am not keen on `googleapiclient` and `oauth2client` but your question looks a bit vague... If you could give some code/details it may help people willing to help.